# XML Schema: using "restriction" vs just using "type" in an element

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm reviewing an XSD and looking for opportunities to make it less verbose.

I ran across lots of instances like this:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Some documentation</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="MyType"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Isn't that equivalent to:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement" type="MyType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Some documentation</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

?

If it matters, here's the type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="MyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: For a *simpleType* you can safely get rid of `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` too. Besides being default anyway, they don't contribute outside of a sequence.

Comment: And nillable="false" is also the default (and is used 99% of the time) so it really doesn't need saying. (Sometimes code looks as if it was written by someone who was paid by the line.)

Comment: Generally speaking, these are sitting in sequences in my schema, but that's good to know. Thanks, guidot.

Comment: Michael - or maybe by the character, in the schema I'm looking at :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for all practical purposes (certainly for validation purposes) it's equivalent. There might be data-binding applications that would give different results in the two cases, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Cool! That probably knocks at least a couple hundred lines out of that schema.